# SUMIF sum value in next column over

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, offset

I'm trying to make use of the `SUMIF` function in Google sheets to sum up points if a cell below it is set to "Excused" However, the condition cell (what will be "Excused") and the points cell, are not in the same column.

The basic `SUMIF` formula I'm starting with is below

`=SUMIF($B$9:$CW$9,$B12:$CW12,"=Excused")`

I've tried to illustrate this below. Using ranges that go horizontally across the sheet in rows 9 and 12. If the red cell is set to "Excused", it should sum the blue cell.

[image]

With how the formula is, it tries to sum the cell in row 9 but in the same column as the cell with "Excused" in it. But, for example, if `B12` has "Excused" in it, I want it to sum `C9`.

Hopefully, this makes sense. I've done my best to explain it, please ask for clarification if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(C9:CX9; B12:CW12="Excused")))
```